# Injectivity of an integral operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, operator-theory, integral-operators, integral-kernel

Consider the operator
$$K:L^2(0,1)\rightarrow L^2(0,1) \\ u\rightarrow\int_0^1k(s,x)u(s)ds.$$
with $k\in L^2((0,1)\times(0,1)).$

I want to know under what assumption the kernel is reduced to zero. i.e. $ker(K)={0}$.
I can say that if $k$  is a Green function for some differential operator this will be true. But what about the general case? Can we obtain a criteria for the injectivity by some expansion process on the $L^2$ basis?. Thank you.

Comment: In my opinion, in this generality it iss impossible to say something non trivial. Nevertheless take a look at "Bounded Integral Operators on L2 spaces" by Halmos and Sunder.

Answer (score 4):

Your operator $K$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator since its kernel belongs to $L^2$. As a result this is a compact operator whose spectrum contains a sequence of eigenvalues $\\{\lambda_k\not=0\\}$ with finite multiplicities such that $\lim_k\vert \lambda_k\vert=0$. To deal with the self-adjoint case, you can find an orthonormal set $\\{\mathbf e_k\\}$ such that
$$
K\mathbf e_k=\lambda_k\mathbf e_k \quad \mathbb R\ni\lambda_k, \quad (\lambda_k)\in \ell^2
.$$
As a result, 0 will always belong to the spectrum even if $\\{\mathbf e_k\\}$ is an orthonormal basis, but $K$ will be injective in that case. Setting $$
E=\overline{\text{span}\\{\mathbf e_k\\}},$$ 
you get 
$
\ker K=E^\perp.
$

Comment: In the non-self-adjoint case, maybe the equality $ker(K)=ker(K^*K)$ could be useful.

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer. In fact, it is quite difficult to compute the eigenvectors in my case. Thank you again.

Comment: @Gustave Well, I believe that the most important thing is the Hilbert-Schmidt structure provided by the $L^2$ assumption on the kernel: you get (in the self-adjoint case) an infinite diagonal matrix with a diagonal in $\ell^2$.